# Como incorporar uma div ao artigo form ou ao contrario?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Estou desenvolvendo um fomulário para um projeto e nele precisei adicionar imagens só que essas imagens representam o lugar das cadeiras do cliente e quando o usuário clica em alguma dessas cadeiras o local fica marcado, só que é necessário fazer com que esse local marcado seja exibido em outra página junto dos outros dados do formulário como nome, senha, etc.Ficando assim:

Nome: Java

Senha: 123

Cadeira escolhida: 1 - A , (E outras cadeiras se o usuário tiver escolhido mais de uma)

Diferente do formulário essas imagens que representam o lugar do cliente estão dentro de uma div(ficando mais fácil estiliza-las pelo CSS), e me deparei com o seguinte erro quando tentei criar uma variável no meu arquivo PHP para ela aparecer como as demais informações digitadas pelo usuário:

```
Notice: Undefined index: tCadeira1 in C:\xampp\www\teste\dados.php on line 54
```

"tCadeira1" foi a variável criada por mim no PHP. Agora estou sem saber como faço isso pois já tentei colocar o fechamento da tag form depois das div's, dentro da div mas de nada adianta.

Meu arquivo HTML:

```
<form action="dados.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="cNome" name="tNome" title="Com no máximo 20 letras" size="20" maxlength="20" placeholder="       Digite Seu Nome"/>

    <input id="submit" type="image" src="imagens/ButtonAceitar.png" />
    <input type="reset" id="resetar" value=""  />
</form>
```

```html
<div id="cadeiras">
    <img src="imagens/cadeiraAzul.png" name="tCadeira1" onClick="cor(this)">
    <img src="imagens/cadeiraAzul.png" name="tCadeira2" onClick="cor(this)">
    <img src="imagens/cadeiraAzul.png" name="tCadeira3" onClick="cor(this)">
    <img src="imagens/cadeiraAzul.png" name="tCadeira4" onClick="cor(this)">
</div>
```

Meu arquivo PHP:

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST["tNome"];
$cadeira = $_POST["tCadeira1"];

echo "$nome, obrigado por se cadastrar e comprar o seu ingresso em nosso site.<br>Cadeira(as) escolhida(as): $cadeira ";

?>
```

Meu arquivo JS:

```
function cor(e) {
  if (e.getAttribute("src") == "imagens/cadeiraAzul.png") {
    e.setAttribute("src", "imagens/cadeiraPreta.png");
  } 

  else {
    e.setAttribute("src", "imagens/cadeiraAzul.png");
  }
}
```

Mostrem soluções com as possíveis linguagens da tag dessa pergunta, se possível.

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro é de PHP e não de HTML, `$_POST` com `input`, `select`, `textarea` e `button`, não adianta colocar `name=""` que ele não vai reconhecer.

Talvez usar `input type=image` resolva:

```
<div id="cadeiras">
    <input type="image" src="imagens/cadeiraAzul.png" name="tCadeira1" onClick="cor(this)">
    <input type="image" src="imagens/cadeiraAzul.png" name="tCadeira2" onClick="cor(this)">
    <input type="image" src="imagens/cadeiraAzul.png" name="tCadeira3" onClick="cor(this)">
    <input type="image" src="imagens/cadeiraAzul.png" name="tCadeira4" onClick="cor(this)">
</div>
```

**Uma coisa que sempre falo**, parem de fazer coisas **aleatórias**, a maior parte dos erros está nisso, tem documentação de quase tudo que é tecnologia popular e ainda existem documentações alternativas, leia e aprenda primeiro, não inventa da cabeça que vai dar problema.

### Documentações e referencias

- https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input
- https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4 (é a especificação para HTML4.01, mas muita coisa ainda vale no HTML5)
- Referencia html MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML (é razoável, mas melhor que muitos sites)
- http://php.net/manual/en/

Comment: Tentei colocar o input mas ele não reconheceu da mesma forma, tentei colocar a tag form após a div e quando cliquei na imagem ele redirecionou para a outra página com os dados do usuário contendo o mesmo erro.

Comment: @LoneTonberry os inputs estão dentro do FORM? Não? Se não tiver ele não vai enviar mesmo

Comment: Quando fiz o que você falou eu tentei com a tag FORM acima da div e não foi depois tentei colocar após e ele mudou para a página.

Comment: Não é acima, os inputs tem que estar dentro de `<form> </form>`, não adianta colocar fora.

Comment: Sim mas eu só quero adicionar ao formulário para além de aparecer os dados digitados pelo usuário aparecer também digitado na outra página as cadeiras escolhidas com o onClick.

Comment: @LoneTonberry mas ae você já tá falando outra coisa, desculpe to sendo sincero, não é por mal, mas acho que você não conhece nem o básico do HTML e está dirigindo tudo isso como um carro desgovernado, muito erro seu é por pular o básico. Por exemplo, o que a função `cor()` faz? Você não informou. Eu não to falando nada por mal, estou falando pra você conseguir aprender da melhor maneira possivel sem sofrer tanto.

Comment: Vou editar colocando essa parte do JS, ela muda a cor da cadeira passando a impressão de que foi selecionada pelo usuário e se ele clicar de novo ela muda para a cor anterior, fazendo isso com duas imagens apenas.

Answer (score 1):

Tem alguns pontos que você precisa arrumar:

- Tudo que você postar precisa estar dentro do formulário (a div #cadeiras precisa ir para dento do formulário)
- Imagens não são enviadas dessa forma em um formulário, voce precisa de um input com o atributo name e o valor da cadeira selecionada, imagens não funcionarão.

Dado isso, o que você pode fazer é o seguinte

- Quando o usuário selecionar uma imagem, você adiciona ao formulário em um evento javascript um input com o type hidden com o valor da cadeira selecionada, o restante deve funcionar perfeitamente.

Com JQuery seria da seguinte forma

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
$('form').on('submit', function(){
   var form = $(this);
   $('img.selected').each(function(){
      var html = '<input type="hidden" name="NOME PARA REFERÊNCIA NO PHP" value="VALOR DA IMAGEM SELECIONADA" />'
      form.prepend(html);
   });
});
```

Comment: Uma dica: não vai dado exemplo assim quando o cara não conhece nem o básico, além de fazer ele pular a etapas necessárias de aprendizado ainda você dá pano para manga pra ele se atrapalhar mais e aparecer mais erros. ;)

Comment: As únicas linguagens que to aprendendo no momento são HTML, PHP, JS e CSS, fora essas não adianta colocar pois não vou adicionar ao meu projeto uma coisa ao qual não sei nem pra onde vai.Desculpa não tem esclarecido isso antes, vou editar a pergunta adicionando isso.

Comment: Se você está apenas começando, melhor coisa que você pode fazer é entrar lá no site da Mozilla Developer Network que o @GuilhermeNascimento recomendou, tem tudo o que você precisa e é bem fácil de entender. O problema é que coisas simples envolve diversos conceitos que, quando se é iniciante, você nem percebe.